# Speaker noise for basic computer functions?

Tags: ubuntu, motherboard, power-supply

I get a static sounding noise(not real static) from the speakers whenever I use the scroll bar in Ubuntu. Should I be looking at the operating system, the motherboard or the PSU? Any help would be appreciated as this seems like a weird problem.

Comment: If you want clean sound, the only real solution is galvanic isolation. Other than that, a dedicated sound card usually performs much better. Your PSU isn't at fault.

Comment: @DanielB It's just weird that it happens based on mouse movement. I tried another monitor, and it's the same thing.

Comment: Naturally. It’s very unlikely your monitor would be at fault. It’s the interaction between your power supply and all the power consumers in your PC. It causes tiny fluctuations in the voltage level that are irrelevant for most components, except for those where analog signals are involved—like sound.

Answer (score 2):

This may be caused by electrical noise coupling from one cable to another.  I would try a quick test.  Adjust your speaker cables, video cable, and mouse cable so that they aren't routed next to each other.  If they have to cross, do it at a right angle.  If they need to travel together (e.g. though a hole), spread them out both before and after they come together.

If this helps, then you can minimize the problem by creative cable routing, or by installing clip-on ferrite beads at each end of each cable...

Comment: Lol I'll check this out. The monitor has built in speakers, and it's a desktop setup.

Comment: @JFA I hope it helps! One of my systems would "hum" when I was using the scrollbar. It turned out that it was actually because I was using the mouse wheel to activate the scrollbar. When I moved the mouse cable, the problem disappeared :)

Comment: This did not solve the problem, although it sounds like the same issue I had. For whatever reason, certain actions cause electrical noise on my speakers. I'm using a different monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a laptop or desktop? If laptop, are you using external mouse/speakers/monitor?

If desktop, I expect your monitor is generating the noise and it's being picked up by the speakers in the input line wires, before it gets amplified (which is why you can hear this tiny amount of static). You can try using headphones to make sure that's the issue, or try moving the speakers and their input cable away from the monitor and its signal cable. If it is the issue, you may be able to filter the noise with a ferrite toroid.

Comment: I'll try this. It's a desktop, and the monitor has built in speakers.