# Computer makes buzzing sound when windows are open

Tags: windows-7, audio, troubleshooting

I am visiting my parents. I notice their screen makes a buzzing sound when a window is open. the tone changes when the window is reduced. The tone stops when i close the window. I am guessing, this is indicative of a failing monitor. Is there any thing else it could be? A improperly configured audio driver? This is a windows7 computer. I doubt my parents can hear the buzzing.

Adjusting the volume has no effect. The video quality is fine.

Comment: Why would an audio driver cause a monitor to make a noise.  The noise is of a mechanical nature software won't change a mechanical noise.

Comment: Audio is fed up to the monitor / speakers via the hdmi cable. As in the monitor has speakers in it.

Comment: What you hear isn't generated by an audio device.

Comment: For troubleshooting, please look at an answer I made for a similar [question](http://superuser.com/a/753471/314417).

Comment: I have seen several PentiumMMX-up-to-Pentium-4 era laptops that make audio noise corresponding to the picture on the screen. It was quite typical those days. For audio processing you had to find a machine with clean audio inputs/outputs. Maybe some chinese factory has reverted to the old ways?

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed mostly likely a problem with your monitor, but it's also possible it could be a graphics card or another issue.  If you have access to another monitor to test with, try that and see if the issue goes away.  If it does, it's the monitor.  You might also try running the monitor and computer power cords through a power strip or UPS that conditions the electrical current.  I have found that with older models, such buzzing or humming can occasionally be caused by other electrical devices or problems on the circuit.

Comment: Even without an other monitor you can switch off the existing one or disconnect the video cable, or just move around the cables, trying to localize the problem.

Comment: I updated the display driver, adn it went away. I am confused.